# How can I troubleshoot Spring Boot Docker Compose Support?

Tags: spring-boot

tl;dr: I've added a docker compose file to my springboot 3.1.x app, and it's not launching the docker images on startup. No errors, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

My code:
https://github.com/flipsbits/security

Specifically, I'm trying to complete a tutorial that happens to use Docker Compose support. I've followed all of the instructions, up to the point where you start the app and supposedly docker compose support will magic up a Redis docker container. However, my app starts up and does not launch a redis container. Therefore, the app does not function.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

I'm running through this youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k62bO-W6Sb0

Here are a few things I've tried:

- I set `debug: true` in the application.yml file, but none of the additional logs seemed useful.
- I ensured that I had the docker compose CLI installed per the docs.
- I manually docker-compose'd from the command line (`docker-compose <compose.yml>` and `docker compose up` seem to work just fine).
- I used `mvn dependency-tree` to verify the app depends on `spring-boot-docker-compose:jar:3.1.1:compile`
- I set `spring.docker.compose.lifecycle-management` to start-and-stop, in case that isn't the default
- I verified that no docker image is launched by running docker ps before, during, and after running my app
- I explicitly added docker-compose to my PATH, per this somewhat vague statement from [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.docker-compose): "The docker compose or docker-compose CLI application needs to be on your path in order for Spring Boot’s support to work correctly."
- I generated a brand new blank postgress + docker compose project on spring initializr and it also doesn't launch any containers, leading me to believe it's somehow related to my docker-compose installation or how spring docker compose locates the binary
- Uninstalled docker, docker compose and then reinstalled with `brew install --cask docker`

Other random tidbits:
Mac OSX Ventura, running via zsh shell

```
➜  ~ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
➜  ~ docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.19.1
```

Kinda puzzled, could use some advice